# How to fully change a border colour in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I did the whole select colour -> fill colour thing but all the edges are frayed, how to fix this.

Also tried the colour exchange mapping, didn't work so well.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/5b6sg0A]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have your tried increasing the threshold setting, to get a better selection?  The fraying of the edges may be impossible to fix however, since you are making a selection of pixels. Ultimately, GIMP probably isn't the right kind of software for work like this. Consider using a vector image editor, such as Inkscape, which is also free.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to clean a selection:

- To remove small holes and dents in a selection, you can try `Select>Grow` by one/two pixels followed by `Select>Shrink` by the same amount.
- `Select>Feather` followed by `Select>Sharpen`, or using the ["quick mask"](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-window-qmask-button.html) by adding contrast (which gives softer edges)
- `Select>To path` followed directly by `Select>From path` (you can also edit the path in between, and remove some anchors)

For more specific recommendations, please post an extract of the original image.